# Webpage with multiple check boxes

Tags: javascript, web

I visit a webpage with multiple check boxes, each box has a his own name in front of it.

I am looking to check or un-check one box but I want to set shortcut keys for each box so instead use mouse or tab+space by its name.

How would it be possible?

Comment: I didnt use anything yet but I am trying to find some way to do it

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question here

Comment: Looks like the [keyup event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: a webpage have several check boxes, I need to check some of them and leave rest as they are, I don't want to use mouse or tab+space, I want to create a shortcut key for each check box.

Answer (score 0):

To make a keyListener in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
        arguments[0].key == 'Esc' // this is the pressed key
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers on JS-based solutions, so I'm not going to waste time on that part.

You can go with the HTML attribute `accesskey`, it's a JS-free solution, and accessibility-friendly.

For example, in following demo, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> with get the first checkbox checked, press the hotkey again with make it unchecked.

```html
<label accesskey="1"><input type="checkbox"> 1</label>
<label accesskey="2"><input type="checkbox"> 2</label>
<label accesskey="3"><input type="checkbox"> 3</label>
<label accesskey="4"><input type="checkbox"> 4</label>
<label accesskey="5"><input type="checkbox"> 5</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

What @jordi-castilla says, make a key listener. Map each key to an input.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) 
    {
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 49: // represents 1
                toggleCheckbox('name_of_checkbox');
                break;
            ...
        }
    });

    function toggleCheckbox(name)
    {
        var checkbox = $('input[name='+name+']');

        checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
    }
</script>
```

For keycodes check this link:
[Key Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

-- EDIT --

You can also use the jQuery plugin Hotkeys:
https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', function() {  
     toggleCheckbox('name_of_checkbox');
});
```

Comment: ask him for what shorcuts want and write to him the code